# How to extend DoFn in Kotlin w/Apache Beam?

Tags: kotlin, apache-beam

Trying to use Kotlin for an app utilizing Apache Beam, and I get the warning that:

```
 @ProcessElement processElement(String, OutputReceiver), parameter of type DoFn.OutputReceiver<Map<String, String>> at index 1: OutputReceiver should be parameterized by java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends java.lang.String>
```

I'm assuming somewhere in the implementation they use reflection to determine the specific type being used; is there a way to work with this cleanly in Kotlin? Or would I need to create a wrapper around such functions to do the conversion?

Comment: Use the `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation before the Kotlin `Map` class in the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to respond without seeing the entire class but I think you can avoid wrapper by importing java map with the alias as

`import java.util.Map as JavaMap`

and then return a JavaMap

The internal apache beam reflection considers only java collection types so a case like this one can happen also with Iterables or Collection etc..